# issue with returning the parameters from the function

Tags: java, function

I have following type of functions first function does not returning anything:

```
void getString()
{
   newstr=str;
}
```

another function returning the string:

```
string getString()
{
   newstr=str;
   return newstr; 
}
```

which is the best method to follow because in first case how do we come to know that function is successful one??

Comment: why have you used both java and c++ tags?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Both functions are called `getString`, but the first does not "get" any strings. The title of your question is about returning "parameters", but neither function does *have* any parameters. It is also unclear what "str" and "newstr" are meant to be. Bottom line, your question cannot be answered in a meaningful way without second-guessing your intentions.

Comment: The first function doesn't do anything, so it is always successful (if thats what you wanted), or it always fails. Where is the uncertainty?

Answer (score 2):

Given by the method name, `getString()` - logically, you want to get a `String` whenever you call it. Returning a `String` is a better call and a correct approach.

If `str` is a member variable, returning it directly:

```
String getString()
{
   return str; 
}
```

Btw for Java-

It should be `String` not `string`.

Comment: The question is flagged both "Java" *and* "C++", so we cannot say if it should be "String" or "string".

Answer (score 2):

If `newstr` is a member variable (an instance member of the object), then neither is correct.  A getter should not change the state of the object.

In your pseudocode, this would be correct:

```
string getString()
{
   return str; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the best method to follow depends on your requirement. You should bear in mind that the function name and its return should be intuitive.

Examples of scenarios:

- If you want your function to be used in ***method chaining*** then you would usually return objects, as in case of `<<` overloads of `cout`.
- If your function can return a error, you would usually return a status as return value.